# Dose Django or wsgi app init multi times in deployment env?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wsgi

I mean, if I store a global int in a `Django` project's memory and modify/view it, this is OK with `manage.py runserver`.

However, would this still work in deployment environment?

I am not sure how production web server(apache or uwsgi) will use my code. Will this app initialed many times in different processes?

#### example:

global_var.py:

```
    command = CommandEvent("start") #a class contains event and command
    var1 = 1
```

views.py:

```
from global_var import var1

def show_var(request):
    return var1
```

#### UPDATE

I store data in memory because I forked another thread to grab data from other source. I have to control and get data from this thread with view functions.

spider_py:

```
from global_var import var1, command

spider_thread = threading.Thread(target=spider_serve_forever, args=(command, var1))

def spider_serve_forever(command, var1):
    while(1):
        if command.str == "start":
            pass
        elif command.str == "get_data":
            var1 = get_data()
            command.event.set()
        else:
            pass
```

I have another thread wait for event, once set, push a notification through websocket to the web-client.

Comment: How are you initializing this variable? If it is static then you should put it in your project settings

Comment: You say you want to modify the value, what is the use case for this? Without knowing why you want to do this it's hard to give advice

Comment: @IainShelvington, I have add an example code here.

Comment: I get how it would work. I am unsure as to why you want a global variable that you can update?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I know I should split the grab thread from django, store data in database and send notifications to a view function. But I don't know how to control the spider without view function. Wrote a tcpserver by myself and listen to command or save command in database and deal with async problem and database lock?

Answer (score 1):

The typical production configuration for a Django app using any WSGI server involves spawning a certain number of processes, each with a certain number of threads. Exactly what those numbers are depends on what web server and/or WSGI server is being used, but a rule of thumb that many people use is to configure things such that there is at least one process per server CPU.

I would assume any deployment of your Django app will be multiprocess, so any trick that assumes something in memory is consistent across multiple requests will not work, because you don’t know which process will handle it.

Comment: Are these process consistent? I have watched `apache` processes with `top`, and found the the number of child processes is not consistent. So if I can not share or even store data in memory, what is the best way to control my spider from web page?

Comment: @PaleNeutron I am not certain, but I would assume not. In the event of a problem the WSGI server could kill them and spawn a new one. If you can't write the value to the database, have you tried caching the value you need using the Django's caching capability?